# Android Notification Tap : Fragment transition when app not in foreground

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-notifications, illegalstateexception, fragmentmanager

When app is in the foreground and receives the notification, the fragment transition on the activity happens smoothly without any issues. If the app is running in the background then the app crashes as the fragment transition triggers before the activity is brought into foreground!

**Code for notification creation:**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    if(newsData == true) {
      intent.putExtra("displayNews", true);
      } else {
      intent.putExtra("displayMessage", true);
      }
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

      final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(this.getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg)).setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

**MainActivity that receives the notification :**

```
 @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(final Intent intent) {
        final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (intent.getExtras().get("displayNews") != null) {
          showFragment(context, "newsFragment", false);
        } else {
            showFragment(context, "messageFragment", false);
        }
    }

    public void showFragment(final FragmentActivity context, final String selectedItem, final boolean reverseAnimation) {

        final Fragment switchFragment = getFragment(selectedItem);
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = context.getSupportFragmentManager();
        final Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(selectedItem);
        if (fragment == null) {
          final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
          if (!reverseAnimation) {
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.slide_out_left);
          } else {
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
          }
          fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, switchFragment, selectedItem);
          fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
  }
```

How to wait in the MainActivity for the activity to come to foreground before starting fragment transition?

Error log :

```
Application has been shut down. Please inspect exception trace for more details.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Answer (score 1):

in the end the proper solution was (as seen in the comments) to use.

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, switchFragment, selectedItem);
      fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: fragmentTransaction.commit(); then use    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

Answer (score 1):

You can wait until `onStart()` before doing the transition, since that is when the UI will be visible (and you seem to be doing animations). Use a boolean to track whether or not you are between `onStart()` and `onStop()` -- if you are, do the transition; if not, store some information about the pending transition and wait to do it in `onStart()`.

Comment: Thanks Karakuri... will give a try.